# Determining how many characters can fit on a single line of TextInput

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

I have a `TextInput` that has a dynamic `placeholder` which can extend beyond a single line. I want to truncate this placeholder with an ellipses before it starts wrapping to the next line. The `numberOfLines` prop does not affect the result.

Is there a way to determine how many characters can fit on a single line of a `TextInput` when the width is dynamic (flex), that works with any screen size? The text does have a constant fontSize.